# Why does React/Typescript complain want me to use my return function in useEffect dependency array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a checkbox component for my project, and I have it set so that whenever is `isChecked` state changes, `useEffect` will run a `returnFunction` (defined in the props), like so:

```
export function JCheckbox({ returnFunction }: JCheckboxProps) {


const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(defaultState)

React.useEffect(() => {
    returnFunction(isChecked)
}, [isChecked])
```

When I do this, my compiler wants me to include `returnFunction` in the `useEffect` dependency array. I'm confused why I would need to track that, it's not used at all anywhere else in the function, and it doesn't change either. The code works perfectly fine without it.

[image]

Comment: Because that's how `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` option in `eslint` works. Just if you forget to include something important.

Comment: What if `returnFunction` changes? As your code stands, your effect won't run if the `returnFunction` prop changes, and you probably want it to (although you haven't included enough context to be sure of anything). If you include `returnFunction` in the list of dependencies, the effect will run when any of the things it depends on (like `returnFunction`) change.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your function (**returnFunction**) to **useEffect** dependency because your function reference (returnFunction) may be changed, So react ask you to add your function (**returnFunction**) in **useEffect** dependency to recognize that and update them by new function reference.

Answer (score 0):

`returnFunction` is certainly used as it is called inside the effect, and it could certainly change as the parent component could pass in different props, in which case your component would continue to call the previously passed in function. So the linter is correct, `returnFunction` is a dependency. However adding it makes it slightly more difficult to detect changes of `isChecked`, as changing `returnFunction` would also trigger the effect. Thus it seems way more elegant to call `returnFunction` from within `setIsChecked`:

```js
const [isChecked, _setIsChecked] = useState(false);

function setIsChecked(value: boolean) {
  returnFunction(value);
  _setIsChecked(value);
}
```

However in the case given it seems that the state should rather be maintained by the parent component, consider [lifting it up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 0):

`returnFunction` is read from props so you probably must include it in the array of dependencies.

You should almost always include every variable and function you declare inside React and use in `useEffect` callback in the array of dependencies.

Eslint does not expect you to include `setState` functions and refs that you create in the same component that you execute `useEffect`.

**Edit:**

If you have a `handleChange` event handler and `isChecked` is toggled whenever the `onChange` method is invoked, **you probably do not need `useEffect`**. Call `returnFunction` function with the new  `isChecked` value.